# create dynamic array for content in child flutter

Tags: flutter

```
child: Carousel(
                  images: [
                    NetworkImage('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg'),
                    NetworkImage('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*wnIEgP1gNMrK5gZU7QS0-A.jpeg'),

                  ],)
```

This is my carousel with static content, now i want make it into dynamic. cause my image url is loaded from firebase.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you want the end result to be? In what way do you want it to be dynamic? I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a StatelessWidget and get URL's of images you want to load through a constructor. In the build function of the StatlessWidget, return the Carousel you've been using before with the URL's you've obtained through the constructor.